# No internet connection with new install

Tags: networking, drivers

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS and can not connect to the internet.

My ethernet card is a Realtek RTL-8029(AS) and is ided by ubuntu as enp5s8

I have tried to run with dhcp and static address with no results.

when I run ifconfig I see the following:

TX packets:0 errors:2468 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:4926 collisions:41871

My machine is a dual boot machine with windows and ubuntu.  The windows side works fine with both dhcp and static address.  On windows I can ping anyone on my local net but with ubuntu can only ping myself(192.168.1.90).

I have run through tons of forums and ran every tool and everything appears to be fine in terms of interfaces and network manager. The IP address, gateway, dns settings are same as in windows where everything works ok.

Ubuntu loads an NE2000 driver for Realtek and I can not find a linux driver for the RTL 8029(AS). On windows it uses a specific driver for RTL 8029 and I am thinking this may be my problem.

Unfortunately I have not connected yet so I can't get some of the useful tools like traceroute

Comment: Have a look at this page, it seems to address your issue: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/ed.4freebsd.html

Comment: Please run this in the terminal and return results here: `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I searched for days for a valid driver with no luck.  I just bought a new Intel gigabit NIC and everything worked fine and I am happily ubuntuing

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a good driver for the RealTek card so I bought an Intel Gigabit NIC and everything came up roses.  I am happily ubuntuing now